# UARTX Rpi Arduino Communication

Tags: raspbian, serial, arduino

I have tried establishing UART connection between my rpi and arduino mega, I tried to follow this tutorial {http://blog.oscarliang.net/raspberry-pi-and-arduino-connected-serial-gpio/}, where I use a voltage divider from 5v to 3,3V.
Since I am using a new rasbian version i used the sudo raspi-config to disable serial, after I uploaded the same sketch in the tutorial to my arduino Mega, and connected the pins, I installed the minicom on my rpi and then I run the command minicom -b 9600 -o -D /dev/ttyAMA0, but I try to type something but receive the nothing on my console.
I am not sure if my arduino is actually correctly connected to my rpi or where i am going wrong. 
I would really appreciate your help Thank you !

https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Uusi.jpg

Comment: A photo and a description of the connections you have made between the Pi and the Arduino will be useful.  Could you add that detail to your question?

Comment: I did edit my post, I hope the connections are visible

Comment: Have you programmed anything on the Arduino? And are you sure you have thw TX and RX set up correctly

Comment: I wrote the code      byte number = 0; 

void setup(){ 
Serial.begin(9600);  
} 

void loop(){   
if (Serial.available()) {  
number = Serial.read(); 
Serial.print(“character recieved: “); 
Serial.println(number, DEC);
}
}

Comment: I made sure to set them correctly by setting the Tx of Arduino with the Rx of Rpi

Comment: There is no need for a level converter on the Pi TX to the Arduino RX.  As a first test I would just directly connect the grounds and directly connect Pi TX to Arduino RX.  Then run your Arduino receive script and echo "ABCDEF" >/dev/ttyAMA0 from the Pi end.  To set the Pi's baud rate you can "stty -F /dev/ttyAMA0 9600".

Comment: Nothing happens, where I am supposed to look ? the terminal after the echo "ABC" >/dev/ttyAMA0, gives a void line, the serial arduino terminal gives nothing